# Failing to embed php in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

Im trying to give a javascript variable a value from php, this way:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var id = <?php echo json_encode( $_GET['id']); ?>;
window.alert('Javascript still works');
```

The probem is once include the line:  `var id = <?php echo json_encode( $_GET['id']); ?>;`

My javascript breaks any ideas on the way around this?

Comment: Is this `<script>` tag created in the PHP script that contains the `$_GET['id']` and of course the most important question is `$_GET['id']` actually set to something

Comment: Also why are you using `json_encode()` as I assume `$_GET['id']` would be just a number. Is that right?

Comment: `var id = "<?php echo  $_GET['id']; ?>";`

Comment: `var id = "<?php echo isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : 0; ?>";` Assuming zero is your default value

Comment: @RiggsFolly thanks the problem seems to be related to the empty '$_GET['id'] ' i have tried to assign some thing else and it didnt break.

Comment: Remember, when a script is first loaded, it has not been submitted and therefore `$_GET or $_POST` has no values. You always have to check that a form has actually been submitted before using these arrays

Comment: @RiggsFolly thanks for the light